# Does std::this_thread::get_id work independently of how threads are created?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Does `std::this_thread::get_id` work independently of how the thread that calls it has been created (whether that's via `std::thread` or OpenMP or pthreads or the OS Api)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Threads have ids no matter if represented by a `std::thread` or some other abstraction.

Not as a proof, but as illustration you can remove any `std::thread` from the `std::this_thread::get_id` example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
 
std::mutex g_display_mutex;
 
void foo()
{
    std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();
 
    g_display_mutex.lock();
    std::cout << "thread " << this_id << " sleeping...\n";
    g_display_mutex.unlock();
 
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
 
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

to [see](https://godbolt.org/z/q3brEs) that it prints the id of the main thread.

The standard says [32.4.4#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.this#1):

> Returns: An object of type thread​::​id that uniquely identifies the
> current thread of execution. No other thread of execution has this id
> and this thread of execution always has this id. The object returned
> does not compare equal to a default constructed thread​::​id.

Comment: @Scheff I added the relevant part of the standard. Also note this: http://eel.is/c++draft/thread#req.native-1. As I understand it they make a clear distinction between `std::thread` and "a thread of execution" (which is not necessarily a `std::thread`)

Comment: I printed the result of `std::this_thread::get_id()` from a `std::thread` function vs. a function started with/in `CreateThread()`. I did this in VS2013 as well as VS2017 (the latter with C++17 enabled). In all cases, the (printed) values of `std::this_thread::get_id()` looked reasonable. What I find remarkable: `sizeof(std::thread::id)` returns 16 in VS2013 but 4 in VS2017 while the `sizeof(std::thread::native_handle)` was 8 in both cases - like I expected for x64. I withdraw my statement that `std::this_thread::get_id()` might be unreliable for non-`std::thread`s. (I simply don't know.)